# Doubt in predicate calculus equivalence: $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow Q ≡ \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am learning predicate calculus. I came across this identity.
$$(\forall x) P(x) \rightarrow Q ≡ \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$$
Since then I have been scratching my head. Algebraically, it can be very easily shown that the above holds but I am not able to develop correct intution for it. I took the following example to understand it better. But rather than helping me, I am more confused now.

**Example**

P(x): x scores more than 90%

Q: School management throws a party

Then, $(∀x)P(x)→Q$ would mean that "if all students score more than 90%, then school management will through a party."

$\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$ would mean that there exists at least one student such that if he/she scores above 90%, then school management will give party.

Both don't seem to match in their meaning. Can someone please correct me.

**Question**

I want help in developing intution about this identity. For this, I request you to please correct me in the example that I gave. Probably by the help of it, I will get a better idea of the identity.

Comment: This is the drinker's paradox.

Comment: Think about what happens to the truth value of $P \implies Q$ if $P$ is always false.

Comment: The "one student" in the $\exists$ formulation is the student with the lowest score.  If that looks like cheating then you should review the definition of what it means for a sentence to be true in a structure, in particular the $\exists$ clause in  that definition. It allows the witness (the $x$ in your example) to change when the structure (which includes the students' scores) changes.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasBlass ... "There exists at least one student ..."  In fact, that student is the lowest-scoring student.  If **he**  scores at least 90, then of course all students score at least 90, and there is a party.

Comment: Strange, isn't it? Here's another mind-blowing fact: Given a nonempty set $S$ and a function $f:S\to\{0,1\}$, $$\min\{f(x):x\in S\}\le c\implies\exists x\in S\ x\le c.$$

Comment: Recall that $p\to q$ means $\operatorname{truthvalue}(p)\le\operatorname{truthvalue}(q)$, and that the truth value of $\forall x P(x)$ is the minimum of the truth value of $P(x)$ over all values of $x$ in the universe (which is assumed to be nonempty).

Comment: So the implication that's bothering you just says that, if minimum truth value of $P(x)$ over all $x$ os less than or equal to the truth value of $Q$, then for some $x$ the truth value of $P(x)$ is less than or equal to the truth value of $Q$.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're reading too much into the notation $p\to q$. We read this aloud as "if $p$ then $q$. In ordinary English "if this then that" can mean lots of different things besides the meaning, which have nothing to do with the usage of the symbol $\to$ in mathematical logic.

Comment: @ryang Done. (The software needs more characters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested in a comment, I'm promoting my previous comment to an answer:

The "one student" in the $\exists$ formulation is the student with the lowest score. If that looks like cheating then you should review the definition of what it means for a sentence to be true in a structure, in particular the $\exists$ clause in that definition. It allows the witness (the $x$ in your example) to change when the structure (which includes the students' scores) changes.

Comment: this is a great response, but the "one student" being referred to by the existential quantifier need not be the student with the lowest score. It can be any student who scored $90$% or less. In this case, the formula $\exists x [Px \to Q]$ holds vacuously.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Yes, my first sentence should have "can be taken to be" rather than "is". In your formulation, to "any student who scored 90% or less", one should append "or, if no one did that badly, then any student at all."

Answer (score 1):

**Using your example, the following is an intuitive exlplanation of $\forall x [Px] \to Q \vdash \exists x [Px \to Q]$.**

Assume $\forall x [Px] \to Q$. In other words, assume that if every student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party. Now, there are two cases:

(i) every student scores $> 90$%

(ii) at least one student scores $\le 90$%

**case (i)**. Suppose every student scores $> 90$%. Then, by Modus Ponens with $\forall x [Px] \to Q$, we may conclude that school management throws a party. Then, for any particular student, say student $a$, it cannot be wrong to say that if student $a$ scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party - *because we know that *every* student scores $> 90$% and we have already determined that school management throws a party.* If every student scores $> 90$%, then so does student $a$ because "every student" includes student $a$. Thus, in the case where every student scores $> 90$%, there exists at least one student such that, if that student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party.

**case (ii)**. Suppose at least one student scores $\le 90$%. Let that student be student $b$. Is it not true that if student $b$ scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party? *Since student $b$ does not score $> 90$%, this implication holds true [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).* Thus, in the case where at least one student scores $\le 90$%, there indeed exists a student (that is, any student who scores $\le 90$%) such that, if that student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party.

So, in summary, given $\forall x [Px] \to Q$, we have two cases: either every student scores $> 90$%, or at least one student scores $\le 90$%. In each case, there exists a student such that, if that student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party. Hence, we may conclude $\exists x [Px \to Q]$.

**An intuition for $\exists x [Px \to Q] \vdash \forall x [Px] \to Q$ is more straightforward.**

Assume $\exists x [Px \to Q]$. In other words, assume there exists at least student such that, if that student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party. Let that particular student be student $c$. Then, we know if student $c$ scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party, or in other words, we know $Pc \to Q$. Now, assume *every* student scores $> 90$%. Well, "every student" includes student $c$, so it must be the case student $c$ scores $> 90$%. In turn, by Modus Ponens with $Pc \to Q$, we may conclude that school management throws a party. Thus, given $\exists x [Px \to Q]$, we know that if every student scores $> 90$%, then school management throws a party. In other words, we know $\forall x [Px] \to Q$.

**Given the proofs above, we may conclude the two formulas $\forall x [Px] \to Q$ and $\exists x [Px \to Q]$ are syntactically equivalent. In other words...**

$$\forall x [Px] \to Q \dashv \vdash \exists x [Px \to Q]$$

In order to cultivate an understanding of counterintuitive arguments and statements like these, I have found the following approach helpful: first develop a formal proof using the inference rules of FOL. Then, follow the logic of the proof, step by step, from beginning to end. I have not included any formal proofs in this post because you emphasized the desire for intuition.